Conditions for function to be periodic
I am investigating the following type of functions
\begin{equation}
I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,.
\end{equation}
where $f(t)$ is a real-valued function with non-negative values, no symmetry and no periodicity.My question is the following: what are the conditions/properties that $f(t)$ needs to fulfill, so that $I(\alpha)$ is periodic, say with period length $L$?
In general this means that $I(\alpha) = I(\alpha + L)\,\forall\alpha$. Inserting this into the above equation and accounting for $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$ results in
\begin{equation}
I(\alpha) \overset{!}{=} I(\alpha+L) = \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos\left([\alpha+L] t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos\left(\alpha t\right)\cos\left(L t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t - \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\sin\left(\alpha t\right)\sin\left(L t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
Further, acounting for $1-\cos(x) = 2\sin^{2}\left(x/2\right)$ and with
\begin{equation}
I(\alpha) - \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos\left(\alpha t\right)\cos\left(L t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\left[1-\cos\left(L t\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\sin^{2}\left(Lt/2\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
results in
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\sin^{2}\left(Lt/2\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = - \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\sin\left(\alpha t\right)\sin\left(L t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{\pi}2f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\sin^{2}\left(Lt/2\right) + f(t)\sin\left(\alpha t\right)\sin\left(L t\right) \,\mathrm{d}t = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Which would imply that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\sin^{2}\left(Lt/2\right) + f(t)\sin\left(\alpha t\right)\sin\left(L t\right) = f(t)\left[2\cos(\alpha t)\sin^{2}\left(Lt/2\right) + \sin\left(\alpha t\right)\sin\left(L t\right)\right] = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since I don't consider the trivial case ($f$ is not a zero-only function) this would mean that finding conditions/properties such that $I(\alpha) \overset{!}{=} I(\alpha+L)$ would be independent of the function $f$ itself. This is obviously not what I want. Unfortunately, at this point I am stuck. Do you have any suggestions how I can resolve this contradcition and how to continue in order to obtain a set of conditions/properties that $f(t)$ needs to fulfill so that $I(\alpha) = I(\alpha + L)\,\forall\alpha$? Thank you!

Since the values of $f$ needed are only for $t\in[0,\pi],$ there is no sense in which $f$ is periodic.Or rather, if it is periodic on $\mathbb R,$ we can just substitute another $f$ equal on $[0,\pi]$ which is not periodic. So why add that condition?

Hi,
Besides $f=0$ I doubt such functions exist. Your $I(\alpha)$ is the real part of the Fourier transform of $f$ and Fourier transforms of L2 functions cannot be periodic (see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25880/when-is-the-fourier-transform-of-a-signal-periodic)

Another way to convince yourself that you'll not find such a function would be to invert the Fourier transform to get $f$ in terms of $I$. The formula involves an integral that cannot converge if $I$ is periodic. But Paley-Wiener style theorems ensure that the integral converges in your case (compactly supported function).
